# Android GCM: Is intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID) unique for every device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm just curious if the string generated from intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID) from GCM class GCMBaseIntentService are all unique for each android device? 
And how is it been generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration ID is created by the GCM server and is unique to a specific app running on a specific device.

You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app

> onRegistered(Context context, String regId): Called after a registration intent is received
>   passes the **registration ID assigned by GCM to that device/application pair as parameter.**
>   Typically, you should send the regid to your server so it can use it to send messages to
>   this device.

And here: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#arch

**Registration ID**

> An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android application that allows it to receive messages. Once the Android application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party application server, which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive messages for a given Android application. **In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device.**

Also that string is not generated by the code your referenced, instead it is generated on the GCM servers and read from the intent by that code.